# Appium WebElement.clear() does not remove pre-filled XCUIElementTypeTextField leading spaces?

Tags: appium-ios

If my iOS app pre-fills characters into an XCUIElementTypeTextField then the Appium WebElement.clear() call does not delete all the characters if the text starts with spaces. For example (debugging output in PyCharm):

```
>>> element
<appium.webdriver.webelement.WebElement (session="fef3ff78-77c8-432f-afbb-67f5f9f5c34c", element="C7000000-0000-0000-8001-000000000000")>
>>> element.text
'           Bob'
>>> element.clear()
<appium.webdriver.webelement.WebElement (session="fef3ff78-77c8-432f-afbb-67f5f9f5c34c", element="C7000000-0000-0000-8001-000000000000")>
>>> element.text
'           '
>>> element.clear()
<appium.webdriver.webelement.WebElement (session="fef3ff78-77c8-432f-afbb-67f5f9f5c34c", element="C7000000-0000-0000-8001-000000000000")>
>>> element.text
'           '
>>> element.send_keys("a")
>>> element.text
'           a'
>>> element.clear()
<appium.webdriver.webelement.WebElement (session="fef3ff78-77c8-432f-afbb-67f5f9f5c34c", element="C7000000-0000-0000-8001-000000000000")>
>>> element.text
'          '
>>> element.send_keys(chr(8) * 5)
>>> element.text
'     '
>>> element.send_keys(chr(8) * 5)
>>> element.text
''
```

Why isn't clear() deleting all the characters?

Answer (score 0):

Try this . This should work .

```
def clearTextBox(element): 

      element.click();
      element.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + "a");
      element.send_keys(Keys.DELETE);
```